# I want use mysql function's variable to the outside in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I want use mysql function's variable to the outside in node.js. I'm doing two queries. But I can't access the variable. I've used global variable but result is the same. How do I get access to the variable?

My codes seems like:

```
// Mysql query...
mysql.query(messages_query, function(err, result) {

    // Add the results in socket...
    if(result.length > 0) {

        // messages array
        var messages = [];

        // Foreach 
        result.forEach(function(message){

            // User query...
            var user_query = 'SELECT id, username, avatar FROM users WHERE id = '+message["from"];

            // Second mysql query...
            mysql.query(user_query, function(err, result) {

                // Add result to global function
                if(result.length > 0) global.user += result;
                else console.log("User not found");

            }); 

            // Message array
            message["from"] = global.user;

            // Concat...
            var messages = messages.concat(message);

        });

        console.log("--- MESSSAGES ---");
        console.log(messages);
        // Users are undefined

    } else console.log("User not found");

});
```

ps. sorry but my bad english

Answer (score 1):

So we've got a number of problems or misunderstandings here. First of all, these two lines are conflicting one another:

```
var messages = [];
var messages = messages.concat(message);
```

at a minimum the second line should be:

```
messages.push(message);
```

to add a message to the array. However, a more fundamental issue is the misunderstanding that your code is synchronous. The following calls are asynchronous:

```
mysql.query...
result.forEach...
mysql.query...
```

You've got the first one right, but the other two are likely misused. It is my opinion that you're actually looking for something like this:

```
// Mysql query...
mysql.query(messages_query, function(err, result) {

    // Add the results in socket...
    if(result.length > 0) {
        // messages array
        var messages = [];

        // Foreach 
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            // User query...
            var user_query = 'SELECT id, username, avatar FROM users WHERE id = ' + result[i].from;

            // Second mysql query...
            mysql.query(user_query, function(err, userResult) {
                // Add result to global function
                if(userResult.length > 0) {
                    result[i].from = userResult.username;
                    messages.push(result[i]);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("User not found");
                }
            }); 
        }

        console.log(messages);
    }
    else {
        console.log("User not found");
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** while the above probably works, it is my greatest position that you just need to change the `messages_query` to `JOIN` to the `users` table and get the fields you want back in the `messages_query`. Doing this will mean you don't have the transpose the results.

Comment: @neography that shouldn't be all that surprising. As I stated, it was a guess. There isn't near enough information, nor is the question clear enough, to understand what you need. Consider the **NOTE:** I left at the end.